# CS0029 Не удается неявно преобразовать тип int? в int, не могу присвоить List

Tags: c#, wpf

я без понятия в чем проблема т.к. вроде во время объявление List res я вроде присвоим ему тип int но во время инициализации как то несходится

```
 public class Res
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class UserControlOtchot : UserControl
    {

        Game_CenterEntities context;
        List<Sales> salesFound;
        
        List<(string Name, int Qty)> res;
        bool StopDoSelectedDateChanged = false;

        public UserControlOtchot()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void FormOtchot()
        {
            if(dateFirst.SelectedDate != null && dateSecond.SelectedDate != null )
            {
                brnExport.IsEnabled = true;
                txtName.IsEnabled = true;
                salesFound = context.Sales.ToList();
                salesFound = salesFound.Where(a => a.DateofSale >= dateFirst.SelectedDate && a.DateofSale <= dateSecond.SelectedDate).ToList();
                if(txtName.Text != null)
                {
                    String Name = txtName.Text;
                    salesFound = salesFound.Where(a => a.Games.Name.ToLower().Contains(Name.ToLower())).ToList();
                }
                DataGridSales.Items.Clear();
                
                res = salesFound.GroupBy(x => x.Games.Name).Select(g => (Name: g.Key, Qty: g.Sum(k => k.Qty))).ToList();  //Ошибка возникает в этом моменте
                res = res.OrderBy(z => z.Qty).ToList(); 

                foreach (var item in res)
                {
                    Res newRow = new Res();
                    newRow.Name = item.Name;
                    newRow.Qty = item.Qty;
                    DataGridSales.Items.Add(newRow);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: какой текст ошибки?

Comment: Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<(string Name, int? Qty)>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<(string Name, int Qty)>"

Comment: мышкой наведите вот на это `g.Sum(k => k.Qty)` - что этот метод возврашает? Какой тип?

Comment: `List<(string Name, int Qty)> res;` => `List<(string Name, int? Qty)> res;` ?

Comment: Мне кажется надо предварительно отобрать записи где `Qty.HasValue` и потом брать вместо `Qty` - `Qty.Value`, если я ничего не напутал

Comment: `g.Sum(k => k.Qty)` замените на `(int)(g.Sum(k => k.Qty) ?? 0)`

Comment: (int)(g.Sum(k => k.Qty) ?? 0) - помогло, спасибо вам!

Comment: `salesFound = context.Sales.ToList();` - какой ужас! Вы всю таблицу из БД вытягиваете на клиента.

Comment: И далее вы постоянно делаете `ToList()`. Хотя это уже не играет роли...

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился приведением `int?` к `int`.

Заменено `g.Sum(k => k.Qty)` на `(int)(g.Sum(k => k.Qty) ?? 0)`.

Comment: Можно сделать проще: `g.Sum(k => k.Qty ?? 0)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Проще, но оптимальнее ли? Сравнить сумму с `null` или сравнить каждый суммируемый элемент с `null` )

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение для Nullable или int? вызывать метод `GetValueOrDefault()`, возвращающий значение по умолчанию (для `int` - 0) в случае если элемент = `null`
Тогда код не содержит приведения типов и проверок:

```
g.Sum(k => k.Qty.GetValueOrDefault())
```